# Textbox only letters, numbers, and -

Tags: vb.net

Hi i am trying to check whether user inputs within textbox was only letters, digitis and - symobol. After he typed and click button this should be checked. So far i did that below. Could you please tell me whether is that correct way? What is missing here is - symbol to be allowed.

```
For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
    If Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) Then
        MsgBox "Only letters, digits and - symbol is allowed !"
        Exit For
    Else
        MsgBox "OK"
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

```
If Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) AndAlso c <> "-"c Then
```

`c` after quotes says that you want it to be `Char`.

There's nothing wrong doing what you have. Some will say, "use RegEx!". You can, but it is not necessary here and I prefer the readability of what you have over RegEx.

Comment: but - symbol is optional i mean allowed are numbers, letters and - . But user is not forced to use all of them they are just allowed. It would work in this case?

Comment: @vbnetprogrammer Yes, nothing is forcing the symbol. It is purely checking if something does not equal a number, digit or '-'. If you want to know if it is one of those things then reverse the logic: `If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) OrElse c = "-"c Then`